# What is the form of a verb after "achieve"

Tags: word-usage, predicate-frames

Which form is correct, achieve+to+verb  or achieve+verb+ing?

- I have achieved to play piano well.
- I have achieved playing piano well.

Comment: Neither: +noun. I have achieved grade 8 in piano.

Answer (score 1):

*[Achieve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/achieve)* takes a noun phrase as a direct object. If a verbal form is used it should take a gerund as a direct object, not an infinitive.

> **I have achieved playing piano well.**

There is no simple rule for telling which verbs take which verbal forms as an object; some take gerunds, some take infinitives, and some can take either ([OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/comparing_gerunds_participles_and_infinitives.html)). The trend is that *stative* verbs (like "achieve") are more likely to take a gerund, and *action* verbs are more likely to use an infinitive, but there are many exceptions ([TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gerunds-as-Objects-of-Verbs.htm)).